# Error to convert a factor value into a numeric value

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data.frame with a column called weight in a factor format, and I have these values:

```
Weight
8.248
5.365333333333333
5.725333333333337
```

and I need to convert this to a numeric value, with the same values, only changing the format.

But, when I do this using this code:

```
dt$New.weight=as.numeric(dt$Weight)
```

and I get this data.frame:

```
Weight            New.weight
8.248             2547
5.365333333333333 871
5.725333333333337 958
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Relevant: [How to convert a factor to integer\numeric without loss of information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418128/how-to-convert-a-factor-to-integer-numeric-without-loss-of-information)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storage mode of `factor` is `integer`, so we when directly apply `as.numeric` on `factor`, we get the integer storage mode values instead of the actual values.  One option is to convert it through `as.character`

```
as.numeric(as.character(dt$Weight))
```

---

```
v1 <- factor(rep(c(21, 24, 32), 2))
as.numeric(v1)
#[1] 1 2 3 1 2 3

as.numeric(as.character(v1))
#[1] 21 24 32 21 24 32
```

Comment: Perfect, sorry to disturb you. But I can't understand why I need to use `as.character` too? I have several difficulties to understand this!